# Implementing pagination in JsonResult

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

We can implementing pagination in C#, ASP.NET in ActionResult function like this

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page)
{
    Entities db = new Entities();
    return View(db.myTable.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1,8 ));
}
```

how to implementing pagination in JsonResult function that sending result to ajax in html view?

```
public JsonResult GetSearchingData(string SearchBy, string SearchValue)
{
    var subCategoryToReturn = myList.Select(S => new { Name = S.Name });
    return Json(subCategoryToReturn, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: What is `subCategoryToReturn`? Why can't you use standard Linq pagination techniques?

Comment: var subCategoryToReturn = myList.Select(S => new { Name = S.Name });

Answer (score 0):

You can use, .Skip() for skipping first n elements and Take() for fetching the next n rows.

```
int pageNumber = 0;
int ItemsPerPage= 10;
var Results = db.myTable.ToList().Skip(ItemsPerPage* pageNumber).Take(numberOfObjectsPerPage);
```

Suppose that you only need 10 items Per page. Number of Pages would be equal to

```
TotalPages = Math.Ceiling(TotalItems/ItemsPerPage); // IF 201 Items then 201/10 ceiling = 21 pages
```

Now you can make Pagination buttons in html. I suggest you use Jquery Pagniation Library 
https://esimakin.github.io/twbs-pagination/

Comment: then how to represent  number of pages in html ?

Comment: Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

stop thinking in terms of UI and start thinking in terms of data.

you have some data you want to paginate. That's it. Forget about MVC at this point or JSONResult or anything else that has nothing to do with the data.

One thing to be aware of, this code you posted above:

```
db.myTable.ToList().ToPagedList(page ??1,8 )
```

if you do it like this, your entire table will be returned from the database and then it will be paginated. What you want is to only return the data already paginated, so instead of returning 100 records and then only taking the first 20, only return the 20.

Don't use ToList() at that point, use something like this instead:

```
var myData = db.myTable.Skip(pageNumber * pageSize).Take(pageSize)
```

I don't have any running code to check this, but hopefully you get the idea, only return the data already paginated, so only return the data you will display and nothing more. The UI can send the page index you click on, the pageSize can be a predefined number stored in appSettings for example.

Comment: I tried skip and take , it's working correctly thanks, but it show only one page how to show other pages? (I means how to show number of pages in view)I'm using EF